# How can I write Interceptor (AOP) with Castle Core or Other libraries (just free libraries) for Cross Cutting Concerns

Tags: c#, aop, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy, interception

I want to have an attribute like this for Cross Cutting Concerns like Logging , Exception , ...

```
public class MyService
{

[Log] // Interception (AOP)
[ExceptionHandler] // Interception (AOP)
public void DoSomething()
   {

   }
}
```

I know that I can write these codes with postsharp but I want to write these interceptions with free libraries like Castle Core and ...

Can anyone help me and write a sample for these purpose ???
I need a very simple sample for learning concepts

Comment: PostSharp Express does all of those and is free. Is that still a deal-breaker?

Answer (score 3):

Autofac is a free IoC container.  I use Autofac with Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2/), [docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html).

Assuming you know why and when to (and not to) use interceptors, and you want to intercept some functionality:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public void MoreFoo()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    public void LessFoo()
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

It needs to be "wired".  I like attributes as you don't need to explicitly specify the interceptor at IoC container wiring.  You just specify an attribute to watch out for:

```
[Intercept(typeof(Logger)]
public class FooService : IFooService { ... }
```

and wire it:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<FooService>()
   .EnableClassInterceptors();
```

Then create your Logger interceptor in another file:

```
class Logger : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) // implements the IInterceptor interface
    {
        _loggerService.Log("calling " + invocation.Method.Name);
        invocation.Proceed();
        _loggerService.Log("finished " + invocation.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can create timers, try-catch blocks, and much more.  Database context and other disposable resources is an interesting one:

```
class Logger : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) // implements the IInterceptor interface
    {
        using (var someThing = new SomeResource())
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

Usually with such a resource you need to use someThing inside your method.  That's a topic for another question! (see invocation.SetArgumentValue or invocation.TargetType.GetProperties() to communicate to the enclosing class.  I'm not 100% comfortable with this, so some comments from others would be helpful)

Then, take a logging as an example:

```
void ManageFoo()
{
    // sorry for the messy code, what else can I do?!
    _logger("more foo please");
    _fooService.MoreFoo();
    _logger("less foo please");
    _fooService.LessFoo();
    _logger("enough foo");
}
```

The actual concern of the ManageFoo method is lost in all the mess of logging (add security and other concerns and you can end up with a big mess).

Now you can rewrite it like this:

```
void ManageFoo()
{
    _fooService.MoreFoo();
    _fooService.LessFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java has AOP with aspectJ and weaving (LTW load time with a proxy, and complile time CTW)
C# (Castle) has intersceptors, that use a (dynamic) proxy as well. You can see it as the LTW variant.

I used this setup in c#.
It is no big magic, and quite limited code.

```
Autofac 5.1.0
Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy 5.0.0
Castle.Core 4.4.0
```

The trick is to

1. define some attibute, that you use as intersceptor attribute
2. define a intersceptor, that checks for the attribute on the method called
3. define a interface with a method and the attribute on the interface method
4. define implementation class of the interface
5. register the whole setup with autofac
6. test/run/go

1) define some attibute

```
using System;
[AttributeUsage(
AttributeTargets.Method,
AllowMultiple = true)]

public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

2) Define a Castle dynamic intersceptor (aka proxy)

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using System;
public class SomeInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
         if (Attribute.IsDefined(invocation.Method, typeof(SomeAttribute)))
        {
            Console.Write("Method called: " + invocation.Method.Name);
        }
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Now, create a object with a interface (dont forget, put the attribute on the interface, not on the impl!)

3) define a interface

```
public interface AOPTest
{
    [Some(Id = 10)]
    void DoSomething();
}
```

4) define implementation :

```
public class AOPTestImpl : AOPTest
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

5) register the whole setup with autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<AOPTestImpl>()
            .As<AOPTest>()
            .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
            .InterceptedBy(typeof(SomeInterceptor));

builder.RegisterType<SomeInterceptor>().AsSelf();
```

6) test/run/go :  run the whole setup:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy;
using (var scope = bootstrap.BootStrap.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
     var aOPTest = scope.Resolve<AOPTest>();
     aOPTest.DoSomething();
}
```

I dont know how it excactly works but the idea is:

interface -> proxy -> implementation
So if you call the implementation over the interface, the proxy/intersceptor  is in between.

Note: If you call other code inside the doSomething() method that needs intersception as well, you probably need a autofac class intersceptor EnableClassInterceptors

Note: it is not the fastest solution in the world. Probably some filtering intersceptor is faster, and compile time weaving like Fody or PostSharp are probably faster. But this will do a lot of times.

Note: if you need something done @Before start of the method, code it before the invocation.Proceed(); If you need something done at the end, code it if @After the invocation.Proceed() call:

@Before

DoSomething(){...}

@After

Answer (score 0):

This lib does what you need https://github.com/pamidur/aspect-injector

```
[LogCall]
public void Calculate() 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Calculated");
}
```

ps. shameless self-ad

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use runtime aop , you can try https://fs7744.github.io/Norns.Urd/index.html

it is very simple, a Interceptor like:

```
public class ConsoleInterceptor : AbstractInterceptor
 {
     public override async Task InvokeAsync(AspectContext context, AsyncAspectDelegate next)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"{context.Service.GetType().GetReflector().FullDisplayName}.{context.Method.GetReflector().DisplayName}");
         await next(context);
     }
 }
```